# Node.js listen and emmit events

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable, eventemitter

I have two classes and i want one class to be subscribed to the other. So 
something like this.

Class one:

`while(1){
 if(true){
   //emmit some event
}`

Class two:

`//wait for class one to emmit some data ,and then start working with the data`

My question is, is there any method, module.. that can help me to implemented this behavior?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think what you are actually referring to are threads not classes, a class is an object template, node.js is single threaded, it is asynchronous so you could create the functionality you want but not in a while loop like that, you must release execution back to node or the asynchronous part of node cannot work.

Comment: @tbking edited my post, sorry

Comment: @SPlatten i can remove the while loop, it was just for an example. I just need someone to refer me to some module that can implement what i am asking.

Comment: Inherit from [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).

Comment: @DavidS, it all depends on what you mean by subscribe?  I'll post an answer with more detail.

Comment: @SPlatten Well i need the second class to wait until the first class returns true ( i have function in that class, that checks rows in some database and returns true/false ). And when the first class returns true ( the function in the class returns true ), then i need to call the second class that has other methods/functions.

Comment: @DavidS, you don't need a class, you just need two method / functions, these can both be in the same class.

Comment: @SPlatten i need them to be in separate class for other reasons

Answer (score 0):

Use Node's built-in [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to implement emitting and listening events in both clients.

Example:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', () => {
   console.log('an event occurred!');
});
myEmitter.emit('event');
```

Comment: I have 1 function that checks the sql base and returns true, false. Where i need to call that function here ?

Comment: In that function's callback, call `myEmitter.emit('SQL_RESULT');`. Define myEmitter in a file and import it.

Answer (score 0):

The default class `EventEmitter` will do what you are asking for.

```
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

// Listen to event
myEmitter.on('event', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

// Emit event
myEmitter.emit('event', data);
```